# How to select many record from database in Select range?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have query

```
select `id`, `name` from `dishes` where id IN (5,5,5)
```

How to select many items with 5 id?

```
id name
5  dish
5  dish
5 dish
```

I got a response
[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfMpY.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `where id = 5` : all rows that match will be returned.
**NB** `id` is usually a `PRIMARY KEY` and `UNIQUE` which means that it will only match one row.

```
select `id`, `name` from `dishes` where id = 5;
```

if you want to use the syntax in then just put 5 once.

```
select `id`, `name` from `dishes` where id IN (5);
```

Comment: No I have orders table, and the dishes column have form 1,1,5,1. I need to select duplicate records

Answer (score 0):

Following your comment I think that you are looking for a join with multiple where conditions.
To code this properly the 2 id columns would be **primary key** and the dish_id column would be a **foreign key**.

> ```
> create table dishes (id int, name varchar(20));
> insert into dishes values(1,'Potato salad');
> create table orders(id int, client varchar(10), dish_id int);
> insert into orders values(1,'Mr Jones',1);
> ```

> ```
> select 
>   o.id,
>   o.client,
>   d.id,
>   d.name
> from orders o
> join dishes d
> on o.dish_id = d.id
> where o.id = 1 
> and d.id = 1 ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | client   | id | name        
> -: | :------- | -: | :-----------
>  1 | Mr Jones |  1 | Potato salad
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=90cdd131f9994e4bed65bfef1d2fc10a)*